# javascript can not access class before initialization

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, instance

I have existing javascript code and I would like to call some new code that is written in typescript an compiled to javascript. I write simple function and from that function I try to instantiate new class. But I get error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Test' before initialization
at runTest (test.ts:16)

Code is as follows:

Test.ts:

```
class Test
{
    constructor(){}

    render()
    {
        alert("Render!");
    }
}


export function runTest()
{
    let t= new Test();
    t.render();
}
```

This is compiled js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.runTest = void 0;
class Test {
    constructor() { }
    render() {
        alert("Render!");
    }
}
function runTest() {
    let t = new Test();
    t.render();
}
exports.runTest = runTest;
//# sourceMappingURL=test.js.map
```

---

main.js: has some function that calls runTest().

Also in index.html there is reference to both files:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "script/test.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "script/main.js"></script>
```

It fails calling new Test()...

Everything in function works, just I can not instantiate any class. It fails with same error.

Initialization? When does class initialize? It is declared before call. Any Idea?

Comment: Please show us the full code of both files. This sounds a lot like a circular reference problem. Also, does your *index.html* reference the original files or the transpiled files? (From what you've shown, actually neither should work)

Comment: Hi, I think I found out where the problem was. I didn't notice the message: 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" in line:

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

So if I just remove "export" keyword that precedes my runTest function, it will work.

Comment: But why is export not defined?

Comment: Scripts in the browser don't have any `exports` object. It seem you're transpiling to CommonJS module format, which is not supported in browsers - you need to use either a  module loader, a bundler, or native ES6 modules.